# Getting The Results of a Google Search Programmatically via Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

I am trying to send a request to Google.com via Custom Search API and get the response with a proper format (XML or HTML preferably). From the Custom Search API website, I have seen that this is actually possible via "Retrieving the Code for the Search Results" (it is [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#searchresults)). The thing is that I cannot get it working. Every time the broken robot from Google shows up. I was wondering if anyone had any experience with it and they could help me. I am trying to use the search results for a small project.

Here are the things I have done:

1. I can use the Google search API in general (I have used it with the search text box)
2. I have set up my Custom Search API to search the entire web.

Here are a bunch of things that I am not going to do:

1. I'm not trying to have a Google search box in my site.
2. I'm not trying to grab what Google says by parsing the Google.com page.

Here is what I need to do:

1. I need the content of what Google returns as search results via whatever API Google has to offer.

I will be using PHP for writing this program. If anyone has a better way to get these search results in a proper format, it is very appreciated.

Comment: has you tried changing the user agent?